# 3d model Gallery

Tags: 3d, gallery

How can i Display 3D Models? i got them in the .blend/.3ds etc. Format and would like to have like a Gallery for them. Whats an easy way to do that? I've never worked with shockwave/flash etc so a Tutorial for that wouuld be nice or even if there is some gallery app for that. I dindt find anything.

Would be nice if i could like link directly to the .3ds file. But 1 format i have to convert my fiel to would also be okay.

should be able to ratet it etc.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually sites that have downloadable 3D models ask their users to simply take a screenshot/render of the model before it becomes available. It's not too hard to do and it's a heck of a lot easier on your websites server not having to open 10/20/100MB 3D files and somehow render them without any software.

There are though some flash solutions (http://blog.papervision3d.org/) but do you really want your user to have to download up to 100MB or more just to preview?

Comment: yeah of course, but i would like to have a 3d view of the model. should be possible to add a flashplayer so if you have a swf fiel of your model you can add it there or something like that. i didnt think about the size and performance ;)